How can I find the first row after a number of duplicated rows?
My DataFrame is:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x': ['a', 'a', 'a','b', 'b','c', 'c', 'c',],
        'y': list(range(8))
    }
)

And this is the expected output. I want to create column z:
   x  y    z
0  a  0    NaN
1  a  1    NaN 
2  a  2    NaN
3  b  3    3
4  b  4    NaN
5  c  5    NaN
6  c  6    NaN
7  c  7    NaN

The logic is:
I want to find the first row after the first group of duplicated rows. For example in column x, the value a is the first duplicated value. I want to find one row after the a values end. And then put the y of that row for z column.
This is my attempt that did not give me the output:
m = (df.x.duplicated())
out = df[m]


what if there was only one a? and if there are only a?

@mozway Thanks for your answer. In my data a is always duplicated.

So the first value is always a and always duplicated? is it also found only in one stretch or can it reoccur?

@mozway yes. This is exactly my data. If I find some kind of variation I will post it. Thanks. You are out this world :)

One option, using a custom mask:
# flag rows after the first group
m = df['x'].ne(df['x'].iat[0]).cummax()

# pick the first one
out = df[m & ~m.shift(fill_value=False)]

If your first value is always a and you want to find the first non-a you could also use:
m2 = df['x'].eq('a')

out = df[m2.shift(fill_value=False) & ~m2]

Or, if you're sure there is at least one row after the leading as:
out = df.loc[[df['x'].ne('a').idxmax()]]

Output:
   x  y
3  b  3

Some intermediates (all approaches):
   x  y      m  ~m.shift(fill_value=False)     m2  m2.shift(fill_value=False)  df['x'].ne('a')
0  a  0  False                        True   True                       False            False
1  a  1  False                        True   True                        True            False
2  a  2  False                        True   True                        True            False
3  b  3   True                        True  False                        True             True
4  b  4   True                       False  False                       False             True
5  c  5   True                       False  False                       False             True
6  c  6   True                       False  False                       False             True
7  c  7   True                       False  False                       False             True


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
    'y':  [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]
})
print(df)

x = df['x'].values
previous_elements = x[:-1]
next_elements = x[1:]

compare = previous_elements != next_elements

change_indicator = np.hstack([False,compare])

consecutive_dupes = np.diff(np.hstack([False,compare]))
print(consecutive_dupes)#[False False  True  True  True  True False]


true_indices = np.flatnonzero(consecutive_dupes[:-1] if any(consecutive_dupes) else None)
print(true_indices)#[2 3 4 5]

first_true_index = np.argmax( consecutive_dupes[:-1] if any(consecutive_dupes) else None )
print(first_true_index)#2
      
if first_true_index is not None :
    next_row_idx = first_true_index +1
    if next_row_idx < len(df):
       df.loc[next_row_idx, 'z'] = df.loc[next_row_idx,'y'] 
    
print(df)    
'''
  x   y     z
0  a  10   NaN
1  a  20   NaN
2  a  30   NaN
3  b  40  40.0
4  b  50   NaN
5  c  60   NaN
6  c  70   NaN
7  c  80   NaN
'''             

